# SELECT query case causing an issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hyperlink, case

I have the following query that works perfectly except for one thing. It checks if a profile image is not in the `profile_img` database for the selected user and if not, it gives a default image. Again, this is fine. My issue is, if the user does not have a profile img then I cannot access their `user_id` for some reason. Their username is correct, though. However, if the user does have a profile_img then the link, `echo '<a href="profile?user='.$comment_user_id.'">`, works perfectly fine.

Anyone have any idea how I can get this to work for user's without a profile_img?

```
    SELECT c. *, PI.user_id, case when p.img <> '' and p.img is not null then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
    on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    LEFT JOIN profile_img p
        on PI.user_id = p.user_id
         and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Code I am trying to call it with

```
$comment_user_id = $comment_row['user_id'];
$comment_username = $comment_row['username'];
echo '<a href="profile?user='.$comment_user_id.'"><div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div></a>';
```

Database Tables

```
home_comments
CREATE TABLE `home_comments` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

profile_img
CREATE TABLE `profile_img` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `img` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using PI.user_id to get the userid, but this is a field from a left join to the image so it will be null.

Use the user_id in home_comments instead.

If you just take out PI then the wildcard in C should work or use a list of field names (always better.

```
SELECT C.user_id,   -- or C.*, 
       case when p.img <> '' then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end img
FROM home_comments AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
    FROM profile_img 
    GROUP BY user_id
) PI on PI.user_id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_img p on PI.user_id = p.user_id and PI.id = p.id
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

---

**TEST 2**

```
SELECT C.*, 
       case when p.img <> '' and p.img is not null then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end img
FROM home_comments AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
    FROM profile_img 
    GROUP BY user_id
) PI on PI.user_id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_img p on PI.user_id = p.user_id and PI.id = p.id
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Comment: Tried this and it stopped a lot of the query from working.

Comment: Well actually, a lot of the query is still showing up, but it is throwing undefined indexes, even though the variables are still working. However, the link to get to non-profile_img users still isn't getting the user_id. I also changed `SELECT C.user_id,` to `SELECT c.user_id`

Comment: I am not sure how to code this into the case, but wouldn't it be something like `SELECT c.*, PI.user_id,
       (case when p.img <> '' then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' AND p.user_id else c.user_id
        end) as img`

Comment: Just take out `PI.user_id`, since `user_id` will be included in `c.*`.

Comment: @Hogan I tried a new case ... `(case when p.user_id <> '' then p.user_id else c.user_id
  end) as `PI.user_id`` But it isn't giving me the results I am looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure how I can still make the original query work without the `PI.user_id`.

Comment: @Paul I meant take it out of the `SELECT` clause. It should still be in the `ON` clauses.

Comment: @Barmar As always, you are right. Feel free to leave an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul That's essentially what this answer says.

Comment: @Paul -- ok use the **TEST 2** section above.  I'm guessing that will work.  Remember copy the whole thing or it will fail.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the or part in test 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sufficient:

```
SELECT c.*, PI.user_id,
       (case when p.img <> '' then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg'
        end) as img
```

Remember, `NULL` fails almost any comparison, including `<>`.

Comment: This is still producing the else images, but it still isn't getting the user_id for non profile_img users.

Comment: I am not sure how to code this into the case, but wouldn't it be something like `SELECT c.*, PI.user_id,
       (case when p.img <> '' then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' AND p.user_id else c.user_id
        end) as img`

Comment: I tried a new case ... `(case when p.user_id <> '' then p.user_id else c.user_id
  end) as `PI.user_id`` But it isn't giving me the results I am looking for. Any ideas?